# How to change tax value in $qoute

Tags: quote, data, sagepay

I want to set the tax value to 0 when order is placed through sage pay.I get the value by

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');
```

but unfortunately I am not able to set the data as per my wish please help me how to change it.

Comment: Try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/modify-tax-rate-on-cart-quote-items-and-recalculate